# WRT54g v3, after loading OpenWRT to it, no Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, openwrt, wrt54g

I have a WRT54G and I loaded OpenWRT 10.03 to it according to [this article](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt54g).  There was no Wi-Fi after loading it, so I connected via Ethernet and can log in to the LuCi interface.  There's an option to enable Wi-Fi.  Enabling it does not enable the Wi-Fi.

Resetting the unit to factory defaults does not enable the Wi-Fi.

I don't see much on the web nor Super User about this problem, so I'm guessing I did something wrong.

I will try resending the firmware again.  What else can I do or try to get things working?  I don't see any instructions about how to configure this (like a 1st time Wi-Fi config), from what I can tell, it should just work.

**EDIT**

It turns out that this particular file will not enable Wi-Fi by default.  Therefore, you have to connect wired and turn it on.  I did several loads/resets, and loaded to v3 and v2.2 to determine this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using too new of a browser/settings.  IE 11 was breaking the LuCi web interface.  This build of firmware is from 2010.

Enabling compatibility mode in IE let the LuCi web interface do its job properly and enable the web interface.